# How do I fill a bitmap with a solid color?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I need to create a 24-bit bitmap (resolution 100x100 pixels) using a unique RGB color and save the generated image to the disk. I currently use the [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c7eyzyb.aspx) function, but it is extremely slow.

```
Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
//...
//...
Bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromARGB(redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue));
```

Is there a faster method than `SetPixel`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This should do what you need it to. It will fill the entire bitmap with the specified color.

```
Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp))
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue)))
{
    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: This shows how to make a bitmap from another bitmap.

Comment: @SanuelJackson So you downvoted this answer because it answers the OPs actual question rather than the title of his question?

Comment: If you add `Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);`, then it is correct.  I can see in the question it also has a code example on what is currently being done to create something from scratch.  Was more or less tired of seeing the  Graphics.FromImage() in all the 'from scratch' answers.  Ideally would like to see a fresh Bitmap from Graphics from scratch.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Fair enough, I suppose, though nobody asked how to create one from scratch - the OP already knew how to do that, and his real question was how to fill a bitmap with solid color. Perhaps you could focus your attention on improving the question title with a suggested edit. Or, if you know how to fix the answer, just go ahead and make an edit to it.

Comment: Switched my vote.  Thank you for updating this.  I try not to edit posts that are old (shy when it comes to necro-editing).  Definitely helpful for those searching for this concept as this post shows up fairly high in google search now :)

Comment: Its working great but what if i have Color in Y CB Cr formatt

Answer (score 48):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.Green);
```

Comment: Could you provide us more details related with your answer. Thank you

Comment: This is the best answer here. In my experience `Clear` is faster than calling `FillRectangle` when you're clearing the whole image.

Comment: Graphics _**clear**_ method clears the entire drawing surface and fills it with the specified background color. There is no need to manually fill it, this is an option that _**clear**_ method has. look to the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) explanation.

Comment: If you read this, always use `using` guards around any operation using bitmaps or graphics, or the objects won't be disposed of correctly.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but usually you would use GDI+ by getting a graphics object and then drawing to it:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

Its actually a big subject, here are some beginner tutorials: [GDI+ Tutorials](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx)

Here is a snippet from the tutorial on drawing a rectangle with a gradient fill.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 30, 100, 100); 
LinearGradientBrush lBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal); 
g.FillRectangle(lBrush, rect);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) to speedup writing the pixels (pointer access instead of method call per pixel).

Answer (score 3):

You're spoilt for choice here :-)

An alternative to using GDI+ is to use WPF (see [RenderTargetBitmap.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render.aspx).)

Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310131/fastest-way-to-generate-bitmap-from-polygons-in-net).

Comment: This should be the answer, specifically because while the `System.Drawing` approach does work, it is unfortunately based on GDI+ (note the plus), which is Microsoft's "less than ideal" managed wrapper around GDI32, and the GDI+ Bitmap has really odd issues with stability and resource usage.  I'd use stronger language but pretty sure that's forbidden here.  So the answer is to use WPF's version (DirextX -based), which is the better implementation in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

always Working with ***regions*** ( **rectangle** ) is much faster Than using **individual pixels**.

Answer (score 1):

Creating bitmap object bmp of Size s (height , width) and Color c.

```
bmp = CreateBmp(c, s);
```

Now CreateBmp method which returns bitmap:

```
Bitmap CreateBmp(Color c, Size s)
{
    Bitmap temp =new Bitmap(1, 1);
    temp.SetPixel(0, 0, c);
    return new Bitmap(temp, s);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest checking out the GD Library.

I'm rather certain there is a c# library.
http://www.boutell.com/gd/

Comment: This is certainly overkill for the OP's question.