# How can I save a color as a PNG image with a specific hex code and dimensions?

Tags: image

I'd like to create a PNG file from a specified hex code, width and height. The PNG file will simply comprise the solid color, with the specified dimensions.

Example inputs include #CCCCCC (hex), 500 (width), 300 (height).

That would yield a PNG file that's simply a gray (#CCCCCC) rectangle, with the dimensions of 500 x 300.

Comment: So you want to create a blank image (bitmap) with the specified color as the default background color?

Comment: Do you just want to draw a rectangle, or create an image for runtime-use (what for exactly?), or create it as a file...?

Comment: [How to create a bitmap programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720160/how-to-create-a-bitmap-programmatically)

Comment: @pasty yes you are right

Comment: i have an option where user can select color codes , with the selected color codes i need to generate an image

Comment: what if i have multiple colors, and i get an color code "#286ECA", how cna i generate in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    g.Clear(Color.Yellow);
```

The `Bitmap` object can now be used for any purpose you want. If you want to assign it to say a `PictureBox`, you can use `PictureBox.Image = b;`. If you want to save this image to disk, you can use `b.Save()` function and pass it the file path.

If you have a color code, you can use `ColorTranslator` class to create a `Color` object from it. It supports HTML, OLE and Win32 color coding schemes. For example, you can use  `ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#286ECA")` to return a `Color` object of the equivalent color.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Graphics** and **Bitmap**.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow))
    {
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    }
}
this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Comment: `graphics.Clear(Color.Yellow)` could be more appropriate here. so that you may not require to create any brush and paint a rectangle.

Comment: I am sure he knows that he can put **Color.FromArgb(colorCode)** here.
Edit: Yes you are right.

Comment: I mean to say that `using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{ graphics.Clear(Color.Yellow); }` could reduce some lines.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an image with a specified background color can be done like this:

- create a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the desired size
- create a [Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is using the newly created bitmap in order to draw on it
- fill the bitmap with the desired color, for example using the [Graphics.FillRectangle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A possible solution could look like this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
}
bitmap.Save("d:\\yellow.jpg");
// or use the bitmap for further operations
```

If you want to set the colors from RGB values, then you can use the [Color.FromArgb method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
    }
}
bitmap.Save("d:\\yellow.jpg");
// or use the bitmap for further operations
```

As pointed out by @dotNet you can use the [ColorTranslator.FromHtml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse the specified color:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    var colorCode = "#286ECA";
    var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorCode);
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
    }
}
bitmap.Save("d:\\colors.jpg");
// or use the bitmap for further operations
```

Comment: what if i have multiple colors, and i get an color code "#286ECA", how cna i generate in this case

Comment: You could parse the HTML color code and use the numbers (as hexadecimal values or decimals): `new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x28, 0x6E, 0xCA)`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code that parses the color string and sets the background as desired.

Comment: @pasty: `ColorTranslator` can do this for him. No need to reinvent the wheel.